# 1 form for multiple database with relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, lumen

Im going to store user's data to 2 tables with only 1 form , here is how it looks like, the tables have 1 to 1 relationship

The problem is i dont know how to get user_id for profiles table, how the way to get it? Thank you

```
Form Register :

email       :
password    :
name        :
address     :


Users Table:

+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email      | varchar(40)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password   | varchar(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Profiles Table:

+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id   | int(11)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name      | varchar(40)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address   | varchar(70)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: What's your expected result and what you have tried? Learn about [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: A database is not a table

Answer (score 0):

In the controller

Insert user first to get user_id

This is your model

```
public function addUsser()
    {
    $post = Input::All();

    $data = new Users;

    $data->email = $post['email'];
    $data->password = $post['password '];
    ...

    if($data->save()) {
        return Response::json(array('success' => true, 'last_insert_id' => $data->id), 200);
    }
}
```

Get id in controller

```
$inserted_id = Model::addUsser($data);
```

Use `$inserted_id` for `Profiles Table`

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in [Laravel method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#inserts):

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId([
    'email'      => $request->email, 
    'password'   => bcrypt($request->password), // or use a mutator
    'name'       => $request->name,
    'address'    => $request->address
]);
```